# Dynamic SQL vs Static SQL

Tags: c++, mfc, db2

In our current codebase we are using MFC db classes to connect to DB2. This is all old code that has been passed onto us by another development team, so we know some of the history but not all.

Most of the Code abstracts away the creation of SQL queries through functions such as Update() and Insert() that prepend something like "INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE" onto a string that you supply. This is done through the recordset classes that sit on top of the database class

The other way to do the SQL queries is to execute them directly on the database class using dbclass.ExecuteSQL(String).

We are wondering what the pro's and cons of each approach is. From our perspective its much easier to do the ExecuteSQL() call, as we dont have to write another class etc, but there must be good reasons to do the other way. we are just not sure what they are.

Any help would be great!

Thanks Mark

Update----

I think I may have misunderstood Dynamic and Static SQL. I think our code always uses Dynamic, so my question really becomes, should I construct the SQL strings myself and do an ExecuteSQL() or should this be abstracted away in a class for each table in the database, as the recordset classes from mfc seem to do?

Comment: Whatever you do, always sanitize the values you put in the SQL query, if you do not already do. Dynamic SQL is very vurnerable against SQL injections. Make sure there is nothing in the data that could alter your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ATL OLE DB consumer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk4h509a(VS.80).aspx) database classes are absolutely the way to go. Beyond the risks of injection (mentioned by Skurmedel), piles of string-concatenated queries will become impossible to maintain very quickly.

While the ATL classes can be initially tedious, they provide the benefit of strong-typed and named columns, result navigation, connection and session management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to abstract it away if it's many SQL statements. Managing dozens of different SQL queries quickly become tedious. Also it's easier to validate input that way.